# How to understand the abstract cotangent complex construction

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

I am trying to thoroughly understand the cotangent complex: I have read that one way to build it is to begin with the following definition of an extension of degree two of an algebra $B$ on the commutative ring $A$, as an exact sequence of $A$-modules $$0\to E_2\to E_1 \to R \to B \to 0$$ where

(i) $R$ is an $A$-algebra

(ii) $R\to B$ is a morphism of $A$-algebras

(iii) $E_1$ and $E_2$ are $R$-modules, and $E_2\to E_1$ and $e_1 :E_1\to R$ are $R$-morphisms

(iv) $\forall x,y \in E_1\quad  e_1(x)y=e_1(y)x$

I have some problems understanding this last condition. Can anybody explain to me the meaning of it, where does it come from and give me a (if possible geometric) example of it in an actual situation?